# A table within my code is not showing up, Any idea why?

Tags: php

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/head.php';
include 'includes/navigation.php';
include 'includes/headerpartial.php';

if($cart_id != ''){
  $cartQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'");
  $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ);
  $items = json_decode($result['items'],true);
  $i = 1;
  $sub_total = 0;
  $item_count = 0;

}

?>

<div class="col-md-12">
      <h2 class="text-center">My Shopping Cart</h2><hr>
  <div class="">
    <?php if($cart_id == ''): ?>
      <div class="" >
        <p class="text-center text-danger">
          Your shoppping cart is empty!
        </p>
      </div>
      <?php else: ?>
          <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
            <thead><th>#</th><th>Item</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Size</th><th>Sub Total</th></thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
                foreach($items as $item){
                  $product_id = $item['id'];
                  $productQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '{$product_id}'");
                  $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productQ);
                  $sArray = explode(',',$product['sizes']);
                  foreach($sArray as $sizeString){
                    $s = explode(':',$sizeString);
                    if($s[0] == $item['size']){
                      $available = $s[1];
                    }
                  }
                  ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?=$i;?></td>
                    <td><?=$product['title'];?></td>
                    <td><?=money($product['price']);?></td>
                    <td><?=$item['quantity'];?></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

core/init.php

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo 'Database connection failed with following errors: '. mysqli_connect_error();
  die();
}
session_start();
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tutorial/config.php';
require_once BASEURL.'helpers/helpers.php';

$cart_id = '';
if(isset($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE])){
  $cart_id = sanitize($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE]);
}

if(isset($_SESSION['SBUser'])){
  $user_id = $_SESSION['SBUser'];
  $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'");
  $user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
  $fn = explode(' ', $user_data['full_name']);
  $user_data['first'] = $fn[0];
  $user_data['last'] = $fn[1];
}

if(isset($_SESSION['success_flash'])){
  echo '<div class="bg-success"><p class="text-success text-center">'.$_SESSION['success_flash'].'</p></div>';
  unset($_SESSION['success_flash']);
}

if(isset($_SESSION['error_flash'])){
  echo '<div class="bg-danger"><p class="text-danger text-center">'.$_SESSION['error_flash'].'</p></div>';
  unset($_SESSION['error_flash']);
}

 ?>
```

add_cart.php

```
<?php
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tutorial/core/init.php';
 $product_id = sanitize($_POST['product_id']);
 $size = sanitize($_POST['size']);
 $available = sanitize($_POST['available']);
 $quantity = sanitize($_POST['quantity']);
 $item = array();
 $item[] = array(
   'id' => $product_id,
   'size' => $size,
   'quantity' => $quantity,
 );

 $domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost')?'.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:false;
 $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '{$product_id}'");
 $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
 $_SESSION['success_flash'] = $product['title']. ' was added to your cart.';

 //check to see if the cart cookie exists.
 if($cart_id != ''){
   $cartQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'");
   $cart = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ);
   $previous_items = json_decode($cart['items'],true);
   $item_match = 0;
   $new_items = array();
   foreach ($previous_items as $pitems) {
     if($item[0]['id'] == $pitem['id'] && $item['size'] == $pitem['size']){
       $pitem['quantity'] = $pitem['quantity'] + $item[0]['quantity'];
       if($pitem['quantity'] > $available){
         $pitem['quantity'] = $available;
       }
       $item_match = 1;
     }
     $new_items[] = $pitem;
   }
   if($item_match != 1){
     $new_items = array_merge($item,$previous_items);
   }
  $items_json = json_encode($new_items);
  $cart_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+30 days"));
  $db->query("UPDATE cart SET items = '{$items_json}', expire_date = '{$cart_expire}' WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'");
  setcookie(CART_COOKIE,'',1,'/',$domain,false);
  setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false);
 }else{
   //add the cart to the database and set cookie
   $items_json = json_encode($item);
   $cart_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+30 days"));
   $db->query("INSERT INTO cart (items,expire_date) VALUES ('{$items_json}','{$cart_expire}')");
   $cart_id = $db->insert_id;
   setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false);
 }
 ?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
define('BASEURL', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Tutorial/');
define('CART_COOKIE','SBwi72UckdsknEg2');
define('CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE',time() + (86400 * 30));
 ?>
```

I am supposed to see a table in my page, but instead I see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6OAl.png

I'm completely lost after hours of messing around with the code.

*when I remove the "else" statement in the middle of the code the table shows up, but it needs to be there.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You don't seem to be assigning `$cart_id` anywhere

Comment: change the `else :` into else{ then replace `<?php endif; ?>` to `<?php } ?>`

Comment: @Nick I think that variable was declared in one of the included files as $_GET or $_POST maybe

Comment: @NorielleCruz possibly but unless we can see the code it's hard to debug the problem. The output of the code suggests that `$cart_id == ''`

Comment: @Mukyuu that is valid PHP syntax see http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: @Nick  (I am sure you already know this) but  `== ''` in PHP loosely typed system is any falsy value.  For example `var_dump(0 == '');` is true.  The same is true if `$cart_id` is undefined (evaluates to true) [Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6dbb06324e7933c23dc637698496b25d4fcfae50)  Without seeing the included files, that's my guess anyway.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix absolutely - I wrote that because that is the condition in OPs code that causes his output to look like the image. And that's why I originally commented that `$cart_id` might not be set (although perhaps I should have written is false or null or empty or...)

Comment: I know what you meant, I just wanted to clearly it.  Loose typing confuses a lot of beginners, and because of that they don't understand why something that is not a string (an undefined variable) can pass an empty string check.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix While that could be the problem, auto-increment IDs in MySQL start at 1, so you never get `id = 0`.

Comment: @Barmar - that wasn't the point, the point was any falsy value equals an empty string, including an undefined `$cart_id`.  Probably the cart Id needs to be persisted in the session, but without seeing any of the included code, who knows.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Isn't that the expected behavior? Why would he want to perform the query if `$cart_id` is undefined?

Comment: @Barmar - while what you say is true, the problem (as I understand it, if you look at the image) is that the `Your shoppping cart is empty!` is displayed when a cart is expected.  Which means the `$cart_id` is a false value, that could include not being set.  I understand how that was confusing because the image really should be put in the question and not linked.  But I was just explaining that checking `$cart_id != ''` included forgetting to set the cart id (or any false value for it), not just a check for an empty string.  But with all those files included who can really say...

Comment: If he changes it to a strict match with `$cart_id !== ''` he'll get different errors, because it will try to perform the SQL query with `WHERE cart_id = ''`, and then it will display a table with nothing in it.

Comment: The basic problem is that you never set `$cart_id`. It's not clear where that's supposed to come from, but if you fix that your problem should be solved.

Comment: I never suggested that, only that the $cart_id is a falsy value when the OP thinks it should not be.  If you look at my first comment, I was specifically talking about when Nick said `$cart_id == ''` because I didn't want the OP to think that meant cart ID was an empty string.... That took way more explaining then it was worth ... lol

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I edited in my other includes code

Comment: Where  is `CART_COOKIE` defined at.  In anycase it seems your cart cookie is probably not persisting the data.  To me it seems that's something that could be stored easily in the Session and eliminate all that extra code just to store the cart id.  Anyway I would print out the value of the cookie and you'll probably find that its not correct.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix it's in the code that I just edited in

Answer (score 0):

I think you must replace this `<?php if($cart_id == ''): ?>` with this `<?php if($cart_id != ''): ?>` to think that your table is referring to a value that is query above. the logic from if else condition is incorrect. Because if this `if($cart_id != '')` is executed then below must also be the same as this `<?php if($cart_id != ''): ?>`

Comment: The `if` block displays the `Your cart is empty` message, so the logic is correct.

Comment: @Barmar ow i didnt see the else thing thought the if is connected to the table

Comment: I hope OP output the value of `$cart_id` to know the value of that variable